# How can I use Cucumber to test drag and drop file uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drag-and-drop, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I have a HTML editor which accepts drag and drop file and image uploads. I need to test this is Cucumber (using Capybara and Poltergeist), but I can't find anything saying how to do it. I found that Capybara has drag and drop support, but it only mentions finding existing page elements and dragging them around. I need to send a file to the browser that's not there yet.

The editor has a contenteditable div, which picks up the file and then sends it to S3 via JS.

Comment: Solved it using the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188240/using-selenium-to-imitate-dragging-a-file-onto-an-upload-element

Comment: You know that cucumber doesn't test anything. All the work is being done by Capybara and Poltergeist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Selenium to imitate dragging a file onto an upload element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188240/using-selenium-to-imitate-dragging-a-file-onto-an-upload-element)