# Google Play Developer Console - image drop simulation by Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, gwt, capybara

I am using `Capybara` and `Selenium` to automate Google Play Store App Creation.

I am trying to upload app screenshot images in Store Listing screen. There is a image droppable box for image upload and there is on-drop event handler for that I guess as below screenshot, but I can not simulate dropping image with following code form [Using Selenium to imitate dragging a file onto an upload element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188240/using-selenium-to-imitate-dragging-a-file-onto-an-upload-element).

```
>> e2 = $.Event('drop'); e2.originalEvent = {dataTransfer: {files: fileList}}; $('#gwt-uid-699').parent().trigger(e2);
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → publish, selector: "#gwt-uid-699.parent()" }
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found out how to do it ?

Comment: have you found out workaround for this?