# Drag and drop local file in browser with Selenium WebDriver and JUnit?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, drag-and-drop, automated-tests

I'm willing to write an automated test in **Selenium WebDriver** + **JUnit** that drops a **local file** into a drag & drop area of the browser. I've looked at the html code, but there's no input area where I could inject the local path to my file.

I've found some interesting resources :

- How to drag and drop an element from the current browser https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egdUfivmm-k
- How to drag and drop a local file into the browser using Ruby (this thread also has a C# translation but I'm not used to these languages) : [Using Selenium to imitate dragging a file onto an upload element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188240/using-selenium-to-imitate-dragging-a-file-onto-an-upload-element)

But none of these are appropriate for my special case. Can someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your kind answer. I tried the Robot class this morning, but it wasn't able to cope with local files.
I eventually found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51iuVOHGUHs), and I'm now working my problem out. Fortunately AutoIt (which is a little bit like Sikuli I guess) can be plugged in Selenium.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver can't interact with anything outside of the browser. What you need is something like java's [Robot class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) or something like [sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html).

Simple drag and drop example with robot:

```
Robot robot = new Robot ();
robot.mouseMove(350, 350);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseMove(250, 350);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

There may also be a way to insert your path via javacsript.